# Android layout XML errors

Tags: android

I am new to Android Studio and I am getting errors for the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:android:background="@color/graylight"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientbackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="425dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/jus" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="Justina Simone"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="425dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_black_24dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="425dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_message_black_24dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="425dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_grade_black_24dp"/>
</LinearLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Android resource compilation failed Output: /Users/cassandracampbell/AndroidStudioProjects/Profile/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_profile.xml:7: error: not well-formed (invalid token).
>
> Command: /Users/cassandracampbell/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/554c09d4342abb7d275bb8bd5da525f8/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 compile --legacy \ -o \ /Users/cassandracampbell/AndroidStudioProjects/Profile/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \ /Users/cassandracampbell/AndroidStudioProjects/Profile/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_profile.xml Daemon: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #1

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: The error message says there is an error in "app/src/main/res/layout/activity_profile.xml" so please share this layout file (and since there seems to be an "invalid token" somewhere please make sure the snippet here is as exact a copy of your xml file as possible)

Comment: @0X0nosugar How can I upload the layout file?

Comment: You can edit your own question (click on "edit" below the android tag). Then you can copy-paste the xml into the text area and format it as code. There is a small question mark in the top right corner of the text area if you need help with the markdown

Comment: @0X0nosugar It is not letting me indent the code. When I try to do so, it just keeps saying to re-paste the code I've already entered

Comment: Then just paste the code into the text area and I'll try to edit it.

Comment: @0X0nosugar Can you see it? I think it uploaded

Comment: I kind of rolled back the first edit - I think the error message looks better now

Answer (score 2):

At your xml file, at line 7 you are repeating "android" twice:

```
android:android:background="@color/graylight"
```

should be:

```
android:background="@color/graylight"
```

In addition in line 48: 
You need to provide orientation to your LienarLayout view such as vertical or horizontal.

Also, last line needs to be removed:

```
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Your root view is LinearLayout.

Edit your xml as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/graylight"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientbackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="425dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/jus" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="Justina Simone"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>     
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="425dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_black_24dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="425dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_message_black_24dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="425dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_grade_black_24dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your last change your closing view didn't match the openning one.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I just fixed that.

Comment: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  /Users/cassandracampbell/AndroidStudioProjects/Profile/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_profile.xml:48: error: mismatched tag.

Comment: Command: /Users/cassandracampbell/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/554c09d4342abb7d275bb8bd5da525f8/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 compile --legacy \
        -o \
        /Users/cassandracampbell/AndroidStudioProjects/Profile/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \

Comment: Your LinearLayout needs an orientation. See my updated response.

Comment: Refresh page to see my updated response. It is this same response, I just edited my answer.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I deleted the last line and that got rid of one of the errors. But I am still getting this error: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  /Users/cassandracampbell/AndroidStudioProjects/Profile/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_profile.xml:48: error: mismatched tag.

Command: /Users/cassandracampbell/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/554c09d4342abb7d275bb8bd5da525f8/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 compile --legacy \
        -o \

Comment: Would you suggest the orientation be horizontal or vertical?

Comment: I have provided an update to my response.  It has the xml with corrected changes. Orientation depends whether you want the views inside the linearlayout to be aligned in a horizontal or vertical manner.

Comment: Omg! You are a lifesaver. All of my errors are gone now. However, when I tried to run the emulator. It says "Profile has stopped" Any idea of what that means?

Comment: error: 15.015 5563-5563/com.android.SPELFIT.profile E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.SPELFIT.profile, PID: 5563
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.SPELFIT.profile/com.android.SPELFIT.profile.Profile}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.android.SPELFIT.profile.Profile.onCreate(Profile.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)